# Prestashop 1.6 - module translation doesn't appear in tpl

Tags: templates, module, prestashop, translation, prestashop-1.6

I made some changes in `authentication.tpl`. Specifically I want it to use the translation from `My Module`.

I initiated these translations in `install()` method of the module and it displays correctly in translation menu.

However when I try to use it in the `authentication.tpl` like so:

```
{l s='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' mod='mymodule'}
```

it doesn't show up. I've tried to clean cache, but it didn't help.

Do I need to initialize the translation somehow (as it is in template outside module's scope).

Thanks!

Comment: your module is visible on this page or you just want get and transaltion var declared in your module ?

Comment: Just a variable.

Comment: so you have two solutions : remove mod='mymodule' and so manage the translation in authentication translate fields or you can call your module 
 (verify your module is well installed in modules >position>hook) then you ll be able to get the var translated